# Java 8 Streams: List to Map with mapped values

Tags: java-stream

I'm trying to create a `Map` from a `List` using `Stream`s.

The `key` should be the name of the original item,

The `value` should be some derived data.

After `.map()` the stream consists of `Integer`s and at the time of `.collect()` I can't access "foo" from the previous `lambda`. How do I get the original item in `.toMap()`?

Can this be done with `Stream`s or do I need `.forEach()`?

(The code below is only for demonstration, the real code is of course much more complex and I can't make `doSomething()` a method of `Foo`).

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class StreamTest {

    public class Foo {
        public String getName() {
            return "FOO";
        }

        public Integer getValue() {
            return 42;
        }
    }

    public Integer doSomething(Foo foo) {
        return foo.getValue() + 23;
    }

    public Map<String, Integer> run() {
        return new ArrayList<Foo>().stream().map(foo -> doSomething(foo)).collect(Collectors.toMap(foo.getName, Function.identity()));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StreamTest streamTest = new StreamTest();
        streamTest.run();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It appears to me it’s not that complicated. Am I missing something?

```
    return Stream.of(new Foo())
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Foo::getName, this::doSomething));
```

I’m rather much into method references. If you prefer the `->` notation, use

```
    return Stream.of(new Foo())
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(foo -> foo.getName(), foo -> doSomething(foo)));
```

Either will break (throw an exception) if there’s more than one `Foo` with the same name in your stream.

Comment: Ah I see, so the transformation isn't done with .map() but during the collection stage?

Comment: I am not sure it’s the only option, but I am quite convinced it is the simplest solution to do the mapping inside the collector in this case. @lilalinux

Comment: It took me some seconds to understand why `new Foo()` is supposed to be an array. If you want a single element stream, you can just use `Stream.of(new Foo())` without confusing the reader…

Comment: I changed the code in accordance with your suggestion, @Holger. No need for the reader to spend needless time on the irrelevant part of it. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: I'm still not getting it.  It still looks to me like programming by side effect

Comment: Which side effect do you think you are seeing, @pojo-guy? There aren’t any. What can I add to improve the explanation?

Comment: I don't think there's much to add explanation wise. Your answer is good. But language wise, this is simply hard to understand.  The syntax simply doesn't makes sense - there's a big gaping hole in the statement where "magic" happens, and I can't figure it out because the error messages when I make a mistake might as well be written in ancient Hittite.